# Seeking a Hand-Written Note-Taking App that Snycs Between PC and Ptablet

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, tablet

I'm seeking a program like [Xournal](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/xournal/) but that is able to have a app for the Android that can sync via Dropbox or their own cloud, like [Quill](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.write.Quill).

I'm okay with Windows apps that can run under WINE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evernote is the only thing that I found that works for this.  Even though it lacks some features of Xournal, it's the only one that works.